# ¿Còmo evitar que tecla enter cree un nuevo div?

Tags: javascript, html, css

tnego un problema que no entiendo muy bien. Lo que tengo es un campo de texto que debe modificarse y mientras lo hace la línea verde ajusta su width a este texto:

```js
let span = document.getElementById("span");
let p = document.createElement('p');
document.body.appendChild(p);
p.textContent="Text";
p.style.position="absolute";
p.style.margin="0";
p.contentEditable="true";
function input(){
let s = getComputedStyle(p);
span.style.width= parseFloat(s.width) + "px";
console.log("Divs salidos de la nada:" + document.getElementsByTagName("div").length);
}
p.addEventListener("focus", function(e){e.target.style.outline="none"});
p.addEventListener("input", input);
```

```css
 #span{
        background: green;
        width: 100px;
        height: 10px;
        position: absolute;
    }
```

```html
<span id="span"></span>
```

El problema es que se crea un div si le doy a enter, se que aqui se crea cada vez que escribo una letra pero en mi navegador solo lo crea cuando le doy a enter.

¿Porque se crea dicho div? Y se les ocurre alguna forma para hacer que no ocurra esto. Lo necesito todo en un mismo p aunque le haya dado enter. Muchisimas gracias!

Comment: No estás notando algo... El mismo problema se da al borrar un caracter, o escribiendo caracter por caracter ;) Así que lo del enter no es el verdadero problema.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El comportamiento predeterminado de la tecla <kbd>ENTER</kbd> es crear un nuevo elemento HTML (que es justamente ese `div`), y lo podemos evitar con [**`preventDefault()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault).

---

Entonces, puedes agregar un listener, le indico que al hacer `keydown` escuche el evento, y lo que hace el evento es capturar a la tecla <kbd>ENTER</kbd> y le quitamos el evento que trae por defecto. Luego de esto, lo podemos concatenar con `<br>` para hacer los saltos de línea:

```
p.addEventListener("keydown", function (e) {
  if (e.key === "Enter") {
    e.preventDefault();
    p.innerHTML = p.innerHTML + "<br><br>"; // le agrego 2 para notar más el cambio.
  }
});
```

---

#### Veamos lo que sucede.

Comentaré la línea de código que remueve el `outline` del `p`, para poder ver bien cómo se hace los saltos de línea:

```js
let span = document.getElementById("span");
let p = document.createElement('p');
document.body.appendChild(p);
p.innerHTML="Text";
p.style.position="absolute";
p.style.margin="0";
p.contentEditable="true";

function input(){
  let s = getComputedStyle(p);
  span.style.width= parseFloat(s.width) + "px";
}

// quito el focus para ver los saltos de línea que ocurre.
// p.addEventListener("focus", function(e){e.target.style.outline="none"});
p.addEventListener("input", input);

p.addEventListener("keydown", function (e) {
  if (e.key === "Enter") {
    e.preventDefault();
    p.innerHTML = p.innerHTML + "<br><br>";
  }
});
```

```css
#span {
  background: green;
  width: 100px;
  height: 10px;
  position: absolute;
}

p {
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<span id="span"></span>
```

Como verás, los saltos de línea están ocurriendo, los `div` ya no se están generando, **pero** el cursor (para escribir) **se va al inicio**. Es un comportamiento muy extraño (que me ha sido de difícil entender), pero pienso que tiene que ver algo con el `keydown`.

---

Entonces, hay que encontrar la manera de que el cursor para escribir se posicione al final, ya que el final **es ese salto de línea que hicimos, y ahí es donde nos queremos ubicar para continuar escribiendo**.

Una forma de hacerlo sería:

- *Seleccionar el texto.*
- *Posicionar el cursor de escritura al final.*
- *Remover la selección del texto.*

Y esto es posible hacerlo, utilizando al objeto [**range**](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Range).

---

#### Lógica de selección:

El objeto `Range` es utilizado para representar una selección en el documento `HTML`, que es justamente lo que necesitamos.

Entonces, inicializamos al rango y otra variable para obtener todas las selecciones en el documento:

```
const rango = document.createRange(); // Inicializamos un rango.
const seleccionar = window.getSelection(); // Inicializo la selección.
```

Luego seleccionamos a todo el `p`:

```
rango.selectNodeContents(p);
```

Y ubico la posición del cursor al final:

```
rango.collapse(false);
```

Ahora remuevo todas las selecciones del documento:

```
seleccionar.removeAllRanges();
```

Y por último agrego el rango al elemento `p`:

```
seleccionar.addRange(rango);
```

Y con esto ya lo tendrías, simplemente seleccionamos, ubicamos el cursor al final (al salto de línea echo) y quitamos la selección.

---

El código final vendría a ser el siguiente (doy una mejor explicación en los comentarios):

```js
let span = document.getElementById("span");
let p = document.createElement('p');
document.body.appendChild(p);
p.innerHTML="Text";
p.style.position="absolute";
p.style.margin="0";
p.contentEditable="true";

function input(){
  let s = getComputedStyle(p);
  span.style.width= parseFloat(s.width) + "px";
}

// quito el focus para ver los saltos de línea que ocurre.
// p.addEventListener("focus", function(e){e.target.style.outline="none"});
p.addEventListener("input", input);

p.addEventListener("keydown", function (e) {
  if (e.key === "Enter") {
    e.preventDefault();
    p.innerHTML = p.innerHTML + "<br><br>";

    const rango = document.createRange(); // Inicializamos un rango.
    const seleccionar = window.getSelection(); // Inicializo la selección.
    
    // Indicamos qué va a hacer el rango.
    rango.selectNodeContents(p); // Primero, le digo que seleccione todo el texto.
    rango.collapse(false); // Luego, posiciono el cursor de escribir al final, ya que "false" es al final y "true" es al inicio.
    
    // Hasta aquí, el texto está seleccionado y el cursor está al final del todo.
    
    // Entonces, remuevo todas las selecciones que hay en el documento (removiendo también la selección del "p").
    seleccionar.removeAllRanges();
    // Y por último, ejecuto el rango con las indicaciones que le dí (el de selecciona al "p" y ubicando el cursor al final).
    seleccionar.addRange(rango);
  }
});
```

```css
#span {
  background: green;
  width: 100px;
  height: 10px;
  position: absolute;
}

p {
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<span id="span"></span>
```

Comment: *El problema es que se crea un div si le doy a enter* -> ese no es el problema? o será que estoy entendiendo mal... Y al clicarse no veo que genere un div...

Comment: Es ese el problema, quiero que funcione todo, menos lo de crear el div. Se me acaba de ocurrir que debajo del e.preventDefault se le añada al p espacio para conseguir el mismo efecto que Enter, pero no se exactamente como lo haría

Comment: Solo quiere que no se creen los divs. En definitiva tienes que crear `<br>` solamente. Por cierto, [`keyCode` está obsoleto](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/keyCode)

Comment: Ok es verdad, gracias

Comment: Si uso textContent para modificar el p, el <br/> tiene que ir entre comillas no?

Comment: El detalle es que está solución no funciona para móvil.

Comment: Esque si pongo esto: p.textContent=p.textContent+"<br/>" me sale tipo literal, no me sale el salto, aunque igual lo estoy haciendo mal

Comment: ¿Porqué para móvil no?

Comment: @Raffaelo pruebalo tu mismo. Yo creo que es porque no tiene un teclado físico y no produce el evento "keypress". `textContent` solo muestra texto, no el HTML. Usa `innerHTML`. Consulta [la documentación](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element)

Comment: Aaaa, ok. Y alguna otra forma de hacerlo sin usar innerHTML, dicen que si lo usas te hackean. Gracias por tu ayuda

Comment: *My bad*, voy a editar mi respuesta, me pasa por leerlo rápido, je...

Comment: @Raffaelo eso son tonterías. ¿Qué se supone que te van a hackear? Solo el aspecto del sitio. En el mundo real no puedes detener a nadie de hacerlo, solo dificultarlo.

Comment: Ok muchas gracias!

Comment: @RaffaeloROCHER acabo de editar mi respuesta, me avisa estimado.